# Unable to connect local server using SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I am able to connect remote server but while I am trying to connect local server getting this error. My credentials are correct and It was running fine a day before yesterday.

Comment: have u checked that ur SQL services r running on local machine??

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Here are some help pages to get you started: [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) If you can update your question, someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @praveen  press `ctrl+R` type ,`Services.msc` and look for `SQL server (Sql Express) `and see it is started or not

Comment: @Webruster,, WindowButton + R not Ctrl + R...

Comment: @AwaisMahmood yup !!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by restarting the services.